# console logging event target id of an object in an array in an object in react

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, target, imagemap

i am mapping multiple area on an image for a web app in react, i want to target their id's onClick

```
let targetArea = myMap.find(targetArea => targetArea.id === 10)

let MAP = {
    id: 'map', name: 'my-map',
    areas: [
        {id: 7, name: 'kitchen', shape: 'rect', coords: [804,1001,1019,1135], preFillColor: 'clear'},
        {id: 9, name: 'bar pendant', shape: 'rect', coords: [516,1294,732,1428], preFillColor: 'clear'},
        {id: 10, name: 'entry', href: 'entry', shape: 'rect', coords: [1034,1292,1246,1428], preFillColor: 'clear'}
    ]
};
```

i was getting an array of objects back with `console.log(MAP.areas)`
but i'm not sure how to dynamically set an id

so far i've got

```
const myMap = MAP.areas

let targetArea = myMap.find(targetArea => targetArea.id === 10)

areaCheck = (event) => {
        console.log(targetArea.name)
    }
```

i'm getting the correct name of the hard set id in my targetArea variable, i feel like i might need a loop idk??

Comment: The rendered component
```<ImageMapper src={unit} width={1440} imgWidth={1920} map={MAP} 
                        onClick={()=> this.areaCheck()} 
                        />```

Comment: also the documentation for Image Mapper says to use _id but that doesnt seem to work https://github.com/coldiary/react-image-mapper

Answer (score 0):

first i passed area as an argument in the onClick event handler

```
onClick={(area)=> this.areaCheck(area)}
```

then passed it around my handler

```
areaCheck = (area) => {
        console.log(area.id)
        this.setState({ areaClicked: area.id })
    }
```

then it suddenly knew what area i was talking about :)